# The system cannot find the file specified and Win32 error

Tags: selenium, web, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever I try to use Selenium module after pip installing the module it shows this error.
I am not able to run my code and it continuously shows this error. It shows Win32 error.
It also shows chromedriver executable needs to be in Path.

Comment: Add error and provide more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webdriver-manager package:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

the code should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

The module download driver automatically and store it at known path for selenium. It will solve all of kinda troubles with driver path

Comment: @Sakalya100 please, confirm the answer, like resolved